# how to find keyword in string in c++

Tags: c++, string, keyword

> When you use a specific keyword, it is a matter of printing out all the words that contain that keyword. You shouldn't use arrays in solving problems.

I used the `find()` function to get the code that prints from the starting index of the keyword until `','` appears, but there is an error.

[image: image]]

[image]

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data = "사랑,프로그래머,의자,사랑의바보,영통역,천년의사랑,냉장고,객체지향";
    string keyword;
    cout << "키워드 : ";
    cin >> keyword;
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i = data.find(keyword, i);
        if (i == INT_MAX) return 0;
        while (data[i] != ',') {
            cout << data[i] << " ";
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Even if it compiles successfully, if the keyword is after the word, it cannot be printed.

In summary, my questions are:

1. Problems in the above code, assuming the keyword is in front of the word.
2. Idea to print the word even when the keyword is behind it.

Comment: `std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if it doesn't find anything. I don't know if it's the same as `INT_MAX`. The result is of type `std::size_t` and not `int`: `std::size_t i = 0;`

Comment: The inner `while` loop goes out of bounds after the last word: `while (i < data.length() && data[i] != ',')`

Comment: @ThomasSablik `INT_MAX` (2147483647) and `std::string::npos` (`(size_t)-1`) are not the same value

Answer (score 0):

`std::string::find` returns `std::string::npos` if it doesn't find anything.

The result is of type `std::size_t` and not `int`: `std::size_t i = 0;`

The inner `while` loop goes out of bounds after the last word: `while (i < data.length() && data[i] != ',')`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string data = "사랑,프로그래머,의자,사랑의바보,영통역,천년의사랑,냉장고,객체지향";
    string keyword;
    cout << "키워드 : ";
    cin >> keyword;
    std::size_t i = 0;
    while (1) {
        i = data.find(keyword, i);
        if (i == std::string::npos) return 0;
        while (i < data.length() && data[i] != ',') {
            cout << data[i] << " ";
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. However, when editing and compiling as uploaded, if i enter the keyword, ?????? is output. What is the problem?

And if a keyword is included at the end of a word, what ideas should you use to print the word?

Comment: Store each word in its own `string` using the `substr` method. For example, instead of finding the `keyword` first in your loop, find the delimiter first (in your case, `","`) and then you can perform another `find` with the `keyword` on that word.